# Why can't I increase the height of this DIV?

Tags: html, css

I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on here.  I want to increase the height of a DIV element the one with an id of #titleStrip, but it isn't happening.  Very frustrated.  Thought I had figured this kind of stuff out, but alas no.  Time for a break. Any help is always appreciated.  All the other answers referred me to checking the height of the containing element, but in this case, the containing element already has a height.  Below is the code.

**My code:**

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.rndImg {
  width: 120px;
  height: 132px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  shape-outside: circle();
  margin-top: 24px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 75%;
}

#featured {
  width: 85px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#titleBP_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 40%;
}

#pDate {
  position: relative;
  left: 77%;
  top: 15px;
}

#titleStrip {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: Lavender;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#postOnStrip {
  display: inline;
}

#inOne {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#inTwo {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline;
}

.blogTxt {
  width: 480px;
  font-family: font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
  /*   'Roboto', sans-serif;   */
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: .8em !important;
  letter-spacing: .13em;
  text-align: justify !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: inline;
}

#topBlogReveal {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 345px;
}

#mainContentBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#postBox {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 90%;
  height: 450px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}

#topBanner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.dCap {
  float: left;
  line-height: 90%;
  width: 1.1em;
  font-size: 600%;
  font-family: georgia;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Practicing with Div</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/newIndex.css">

  <!-- Add icon library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <!-- Add icon library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!--Include google fonts-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin&family=Lato&family=Lobster&family=Montserrat&family=Open+Sans&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;1,400&family=Roboto&family=Viaoda+Libre&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="javascript/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button 
      class="navbar-toggler" 
      type="button" 
      data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" 
      aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" 
      aria-expanded="false" 
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">About</a>
      
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index_the_real_thing.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="philosophy.html">Philosphy <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="spirituality.html">Spiritualism</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="socialChange.html">Social Change</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!--Zeroth Row Banner Image-->
  <div class="row" id="row0">
    <div class="col" id="row0_col1">
      <img 
        class="banPics" 
        id="topBanner" 
        alt="There will always be something to read here..." 
        src="Images/bannerPlaceholder.jpg"
      >
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!--First Blog Post-->
    <div class="row" id="row1">
      <div class="col" id="row1_col1">
        <div id="postBox">
          <div id="titleStrip"><a href="#" id="featured" class="btn-sm btn-primary">Featured</a>
            <h3 id="titleBP_1">Blog Post #1</h3>
          </div>
          <div id="postOnStrip">
            <p id="pDate"><b>Posted On: </b><em>June 23, 2021</em></p>
            <hr class="divider">
          </div>
          <div id="mainContentBox">
            <div id="inOne">
              <img id="topBgImg" class="rndImg" src="Images/473a9b83088edfa35bdba1b7691056ad.jpg">

              <p class="blogTxt"><span class="dCap">W</span>hat if the opiate epidemic runs deeper than purple bruises and scabrous veins running yup and down the arms of our nation's heroine addicts? What if it isn't just a socio economic problem, nor the result of international
                anatagonisms vis a vis the black marget drug trade, but rather the first symptoms of a looming existential crisis for humanity at large. The cancer patient swallows pills to ease the aching malignancy bloomin down there in the organs and
                tissues, the mess of physicality from which our consciousness is supposed to arise out of. But someti,es, the cancer patient blajets hersel fin morphine just to kill that deeper ache which starts when one percieves the horizon of their
                own impending demnise. And who can blame them Life is hard.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="inTwo">
              <p class="blogTxt">What if the opiate epidemic runs deeper than purple bruises and scabrous veins running yup and down the arms of our nation's heroine addicts? What if it isn't just a socio economic problem, nor the result of international anatagonisms vis
                a vis the black marget drug trade, but rather the first symptoms of a looming existential crisis for humanity at large. The cancer patient swallows pills to ease the aching malignancy bloomin down there in the organs and tissues, the mess
                of physicality from which our consciousness is supposed to arise out of. But someti,es, the cancer patient blajets hersel fin morphine just to kill that deeper ache which starts when one percieves the horizon of their own impending demnise.
                And who can blame them Life is hard.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="topBlogReveal">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="row1">
      <div class="col" id="row1_col1">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="row1">
      <div class="col" id="row1_col1">
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

The most frustrated EVER.  I had this page working, but then I started rebuilding it, and here I am back at square one feeling like a dullard

Comment: first correct the error in css in  .blogTxt {....   font-family: font-family: 'Alegreya', serif; to .blogTxt {...font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent element `div#postBox` has the CSS property `display: flex;`, which stretches the child div to its own size. If you remove `display: flex;` in `#postBox`, you will find that `#titleStrip` will be `120px` of height. Ofcourse, the styling for `#postBox` will break, so you have to figure out something there. CSS Tricks has [an excellent guide on flexbox here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thanks, I had a sneaking suspicion it had something to do with flexbox, and, all morning I had a feeling I should master that concept entirely if I'm to really build this from scratch.  Thanks for saving me from any further head banging.